# How to see My newly added place in Google maps after adding by Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I am trying to add a place to google maps by using Google places API's. I am able to get the response as place id for the given particular area latitude and longitude. Where can I Get the view of that Map after adding my new Place ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Places API documentation for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/add-place)...

> The resulting Place object has a unique place ID, which your app can
> use from that point on to retrieve the place details. Added places are
> also available after a short time in the results of get-current-place
> requests initiated by your app, and in a place picker displayed by
> your app. Scoping is determined by the project ID used to generate
> your API key.
>
> Newly-added places enter a moderation queue to be considered for
> addition to the Google Places database. Places that are not accepted
> by the moderation process will continue to be retrievable through the
> place ID in the app that submitted them, but will no longer appear in
> the results of get-current-place requests, the api picker, or any
> other API method. Places that pass moderation will be visible to all
> apps and on Google Maps.

This means you should be able to see it within your app via the PlacePicker, but will not see it inside other applications or Google Maps until it passes the moderation process. If it does not pass moderation, it will stop showing on the PlacePicker even within your own application.

From what I can tell the process is similar even if you are using the iOS or web API.